# Re-install option not showing in the installer

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb-installation

So I have completely bricked my system and decided to re-install Ubuntu from a LiveUSB. But I don't want to lose my data, so I wanted to install it on top of the pre-existing installation (which the installer detects correctly in the partition manager). However, there's no option for "re-install" that has always been there before, only "Install alongside Windows AND the previous install", "Erase everything", and "Manual partition".

How come?

Alternatively, if I go to manual partitioning and just assign the partition with my previous install as my "/" partition, will it not touch my home folder?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I saw it in the search result but didn't even open since it was 9 years old :)